# Passing innerhtml of a label to a variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to pass the inner html of a label in HTML form to a variable in PHP via POST method. but I don't know how to do so. Here is my code .

```
    <select id="ops" name="select" onChange="myfunction(this)">

                    <option>PIck item </option>
                    <option value="pepsi">pepsi</option>
                    <option value="coke">coke</option>
                    <option value="fanta">Fanta</option>

    </select><br><br>


<label id="lb" style="display:none" >Qty</label>

<input type="text" name='qtytext' id="num" style="display:none" placeholder="Quantity" onKeyUp="return validateform()"  onSelect="return validateform()" onFocus="myfun2()" required/ >


<label id="lb2" style="display:none" name='price' >  </label>
```

I want to pass the innerHTML of the above Label to a variable in PHP. InnerHtml has been already set by JS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the label via JS, you should set the value of another input field in the form simultaneously:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="labelContent" value="theValueToSet" />
</form>
```

Comment: will u plz explain value attribute here?

Comment: "value" should be set to the label's innerHTML. Of course you will need a name attribute in the input as well... I add it in the answer.

Comment: i m confused about the values of NAME and VALUE attribute.. kindly explain them

Comment: I assumed you're clear with that, since you're already using a form element, where name and value also appear as they should. NAME identifies your form element during further processing, VALUE contains its value. E.g. in PHP, you may receive $_POST['labelContent'] which has a value of "theValueToSelect".

Comment: i just have a confusion abput the value of a hidden attribute

Comment: just use it as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When updating `innerHTML` of label, put the value in a hidden form input. And, finally post the form to the server.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed, value of hidden input will be the value of the label.

Comment: What is the value of label in current scenario ??

Comment: The value that you were updating earlier in the label. To be precise, it is the json string.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a form or AJAX to post the values and get those value on your action page by `var_dump( $_POST );`